# Django: can I verify email using otp in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have a question about Django authentication. Is it possible for a user, before they create an account they pass through these steps?

1. Enter only their email first
2. I send OTP to their email
3. They verify their email using the OTP
4. I then ask for their username, password 1, password 2

Please, if anybody knows whether something like this is possible using the Django REST framework, I would really appreciate an answer.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use [Djoser](https://djoser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)**

Through Djoser you can authenticate user through mail.

But it wont work in as you have mentioned. It uses different authentication methodology

1. Create an User model with name, mail ID and password
2. Send Verification link to user mail ID
3. Authenticate after a call back URL
4. User Authorized and gets JWT tokens

To work with your app model, I have an solution

1. Create user with dummy username, password with proper  Mail ID
2. After verification with proper mail ID, Let them change their username and password.

**Important :**  Use UserModel.id ( i.e primary key) for identifying user because some people might spam others mail ID, multiple same email ID will occur and  causes errors.

When the original user authenticates delete all other unverified users using UserModel.is_active